# Как правильно организовать стек активити?

Tags: android, android-intent, стек

У меня есть две активити А и В. При нажатии на пункт меню я перехожу из А в В. Затем чтобы вернуться назад я нажимаю пункт в меню в активити В (с помощью интента) и уничтожаю активити В (finish()). Но далее при выходе из активити А я, естественно, перехожу на ранее созданную ее копию. Мне нужно чтобы эта копия как-то уничтожалась из стека. Перепробовал все флаги. Пробовал в манифесте прописывать singleInstance. Но это не то. Как лучше поступить в этой ситуации?

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` такой тоже пробовали?

Comment: пробовал не помогает

Comment: Получается у вас в стеке лежит две одинаковых активности (А-В-А)? Так бывает? Вы пробовали `finish();` у В не вызывать (ибо зачем) и просто с `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` А запускать?

Comment: Спасибо. Все правильно. Оказывается я addFlags ставил после startActivity().